# Copy partial xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have input xml like below and expecting output as below.

Input xml :

```
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:api:pis:BaseComponents">
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Item>
        <AutoPay>false</AutoPay>
        <ListingDetails>
            <Adult>false</Adult>
            <EndingReason>NotAvailable</EndingReason>
        </ListingDetails>
        <Duration>35</Duration>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
            <CalculatedShippingRate>
                <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
                <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
            </CalculatedShippingRate>
            <SalesTax>
                <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
                <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
            </SalesTax>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>ShippingMethodStandard</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
                <ShippingTimeMin>1</ShippingTimeMin>
                <ShippingTimeMax>6</ShippingTimeMax>
                <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
           <ExcludeShipToLocation>PO Box</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>true</SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ShipToLocations>US</ShipToLocations>
        <HideFromSearch>false</HideFromSearch>
    </Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```

The output xml should looks like :

```
<ShippingDetails>
            <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
            <CalculatedShippingRate>
                <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
                <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
            </CalculatedShippingRate>
            <SalesTax>
                <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
                <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
            </SalesTax>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>ShippingMethodStandard</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
                <ShippingTimeMin>1</ShippingTimeMin>
                <ShippingTimeMax>6</ShippingTimeMax>
                <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
           <ExcludeShipToLocation>PO Box</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>true</SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>
        </ShippingDetails>
```

Hence i have write xslt some thing like below which is not working. I am using xslt 2.0. Kindly help me with this xslt transformation.

XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ItemFee>
            <product_id></product_id>
            <Details>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="/ns:GetItemResponse/ns:Ack = 'Failure'">
                        <Ack>Failure</Ack>
                        <itemid>0</itemid>
                        <ebay_listing_status>-3</ebay_listing_status>
                        <status>FALSE</status>
                        <listed_timestamp>now</listed_timestamp>
                        <listing_reason>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/ns:GetItemResponse/ns:Errors[position()=last()]/ns:LongMessage"/>
                        </listing_reason>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </Details>
        </ItemFee>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ShippingDetails">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please explain the required logic of the transformation **in words**, not (only) by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply extract an element and strip the namespace then it should suffice to use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:api:pis:BaseComponents"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/GetItemResponse/Item[1]/ShippingDetails[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I used Saxon 9.7 HE against your posted input sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:api:pis:BaseComponents">
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Item>
        <AutoPay>false</AutoPay>
        <ListingDetails>
            <Adult>false</Adult>
            <EndingReason>NotAvailable</EndingReason>
        </ListingDetails>
        <Duration>35</Duration>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
            <CalculatedShippingRate>
                <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
                <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
            </CalculatedShippingRate>
            <SalesTax>
                <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
                <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
            </SalesTax>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingService>ShippingMethodStandard</ShippingService>
                <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
                <ShippingTimeMin>1</ShippingTimeMin>
                <ShippingTimeMax>6</ShippingTimeMax>
                <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
            <ExcludeShipToLocation>PO Box</ExcludeShipToLocation>
            <SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>true</SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <ShipToLocations>US</ShipToLocations>
        <HideFromSearch>false</HideFromSearch>
    </Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ShippingDetails>
                        <ApplyShippingDiscount>false</ApplyShippingDiscount>
                        <CalculatedShippingRate>
                                <WeightMajor measurementSystem="English" unit="lbs">0</WeightMajor>
                                <WeightMinor measurementSystem="English" unit="oz">0</WeightMinor>
                        </CalculatedShippingRate>
                        <SalesTax>
                                <SalesTaxPercent>0.0</SalesTaxPercent>
                                <ShippingIncludedInTax>false</ShippingIncludedInTax>
                        </SalesTax>
                        <ShippingServiceOptions>
                                <ShippingService>ShippingMethodStandard</ShippingService>
                                <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceCost>
                                <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
                                <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                                <ExpeditedService>false</ExpeditedService>
                                <ShippingTimeMin>1</ShippingTimeMin>
                                <ShippingTimeMax>6</ShippingTimeMax>
                                <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
                        </ShippingServiceOptions>
                        <ExcludeShipToLocation>PO Box</ExcludeShipToLocation>
                        <SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>true</SellerExcludeShipToLocationsPreference>
                </ShippingDetails>
```

Comment: This is not giving expected result. This producing empty XML as output. We can cross check in online xslt transformer tool too.

Comment: @Simbu, I have added information about the XSLT 2.0 processor I used to test and the test input and output data, it seems corrent. You will need to tell us which XSLT 2.0 processor you used.